# Which SQL Power Architect type to specify for [PostgreSQL] UUIDs/GUIDs in new column property template/UI?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, uuid

I have inherited maintaining and extending SQL Power Architect projects in source control which are used to generate the DDL for project DB schemas. We are currently using PostgreSQL 9.5 and SQL Power Architect 1.0.8. (We are using SQL Power Architect to attempt to keep the schema DB-agnostic, in the event the project will eventually migrate to a different type of DB.)

**If it is possible to specify UUID columns** (aka GUIDs) in Power Architect for table schemas we generate, **can anyone tell me which Type needs to specified for the column property of those provided in the Power Architect UI's type list?** (ARRAY, DISTINCT, LONGNVARCHAR/LONGVARCHAR, VARCHAR/NVARCHAR, OTHER, UNKNOWN, etc.)
**Do any of these equate to/generate a UUID column?**

Comment: Here's a *really old* post off the Power Architect forums that recommends making a custom type for UUID: http://www.sqlpower.ca/forum/posts/list/2706.page This is untested, YMMV, etc. Hope it helps though.

Comment: @JacobH thanks for letting me know about that thread! I just tracked down this video on creating custom data types in SQL Power Architect: [link](https://youtu.be/XXvwMJFnprE) and that appears to be a feature of "Enterprise Edition", which is pretty sad... and not really worth $50k, so I guess I'll have to settle for using BIGINTs or something equally silly.

Comment: varchar(38) I believe for guids. Good luck!